# Use assets in scss in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm having trouble inserting an image as a background-image in scss. I have image in my theme at: `custom/plugins/MyTheme/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/assets/img/my-image.png`
and i am trying to use this image in a scss file. When I use `./psh.phar storefront:build` I can see image in a storefront, but when I use `./psh.phar storefront:hot-proxy` I have an error:

`This relative module was not found: * ../assets/img/my-image.png in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-3!/app/var/theme-entry.scss`

In scss I use the path: `background-image: url("../assets/img/my-image.png");`

How to properly add a file in scss?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the file relative to the theme css, then refer directly from there. Like "images/abc.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this solution from the forum
https://forum.shopware.com/discussion/70245/plugin-assets-in-scss-verlinken

In my theme I create this variable and use it like this

```
$bundle-path: '../../..//bundles/mybundle/';
$icon-chevron-right: url($bundle-path + '/assets/icon/chevron-right-xs.svg');
```

Or you can hard-code it like this

```
$icon-chevron-right: url(/bundles/mytheme/assets/icon/chevron-right-xs.svg) !default;
```